# How to add a directory which contains .pyc to git with .pyc in .gitignore?

Tags: git, python-2.7, github, py2exe, gitignore

I'm using `py2exe` to build windows executable from a python script. This creates a `collect-2.7` directory which contains compiled version of all the core python files in `.pyc`.

I need to commit these compiled files with the `.exe` to work with. But `.pyc` is added in `.gitignore` which omits the `collect-2.7` directory.

How could I add the `collect-2.7` directory without removing `.pyc` in `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have .gitignore in each folder. And can use !*.pyc entry or sepcific files listed to unignore them.